# SQL, how to have the lowest average?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following database

```
Student (NumStu, Name, Surname, BirthDate, Street, PC, City)
Teach (CodeTeach, Label, Coef)
Exam (numexam, DateExam, Place, #CodeTeach)
Notation (#NumStu, #NumTeach, Note)
```

And I want to have the list of the students who have the lowest average in the teach of Computer Science.

How to do it?

Comment: GROUP BY, AVG, ORDER BY...

Comment: can you be more descriptive.

Comment: I can't be more descriptive about what I want :/

Comment: Of course you can be more descriptive. You could provide sample input and expected output data, for a start. You could also provide the actual table structures (including datatypes, constraints etc).

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to select all students sorted by teach in Computer Science or only 1 student with lowest grade? You should add more description.

If students are inserted in `Student` table and their teaching grades in table `Teach` should be something like that(I can help you correctly after you give more detailed description):

```
SELECT S.NumStu, S.Name, S.Surname, S.BirthDate, S.Street, S.PC, S.City, T.ComputerScience
FROM Student AS S
INNER JOIN Teach AS T
ON T.AssociatedColumn = S.AssociatedColumn 
ORDER BY T.ComputerScience -- Here you order students list from lowest grade (ascending)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Student, Notation
ON Student.NumStu = Notation.NumStu
WHERE Notation.Note =    
(
    SELECT MIN(AVG(Note))
    FROM Notation
    GROUP BY NumStu
)
```

Explanation: This request will show you everything from the tables Student and Notation, when Note will be equal to the Minimum of the Average of Note.

I am not certain it will work, waiting for feedback.

P.-S: Am french too

Comment: Bonjour, vu que je suis moyen en Anglais, je vais reformuler le tout en Francais pour vous.

J'ai le truc suivant:

Etudiant (NumEtu, Nom, Prenom, DateNaiss, Rue, CP, Ville)
Matiere (CodeMat, Libelle, Coef)
Epreuve (numepreuve, DateEpreuve, Lieu, #CodeMat)
Notation (#NumEtu, #NumEpreuve, Note)

Et je dois avoir:

- Liste des étudiants qui ont obtenu la plus petite moyenne en Informatique
-Liste des étudiants qui ont obtenu la meilleure moyenne

Merci d'avance :)

Comment: Je suis pas sûr du "MIN(AVG(Note))", mais si ça marche, il suffit de changer le MIN en MAX pour avoir la moins bonne ou la meilleure moyenne.